# How to Deploy a ClearML Agent in a k8s setting?

Tags: kubernetes, clearml

I want to deploy a ClearML agent in the kubernetes environment while using the ClearML's Free Tier Demo server.
I was able to deploy the Agent pod in the k8s cluster with the `allegroai/clearml-agent` docker image. But was not able to link this agent to the ClearML Demo server.
Can anyone help me with solving this issue of configuring the API access and secret keys for the k8s pod of CLearML Agent.

Comment: could you share document details also if you are following any for this deployment?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm a member of the ClearML team

In case you're referring to the ClearML Demo Server (at https://demo.clear.ml), we do not recommend running your agents against it, as it is reset daily (all contents deleted) and is meant only as a show-case server.

If you're referring to the ClearML Free Hosted Server (using the free tier) at https://app.clear.ml, you can simply create a free account, obtain credentials for your use and use these for the agent.

Comment: So, SO became your support platform :/